# How to map array in flatlist in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have functionality which will return me days of the week. Then I am mapping that array into `ScrollView`. I am able to do this succesfully.

getting days of week functionality:

```
const [weekArray, changeWeekArrayState] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    var now = moment();
    let arrayDays = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      var day = now.format('ddd');
      var date = now.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
      if (i == 0) {
        day = 'Today';
      } else if (i == 1) {
        day = 'Tommorow';
      }
      arrayDays.push({
        day: day,
        date: date,
      });
      now.add(1, 'days');
    }
    changeWeekArrayState(arrayDays);
    console.log(weekArray);
  }, []);
```

Below is my code:

```
<ScrollView
  horizontal={true}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
  {weekArray.map((item, index) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      index={index}
      onPress={() => setIndexSelect(index)}
      key={index}>
      <Text>
        {index === weekArray.length - 1 ? ` ${item.day} ` : ` ${item.day} | `}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ))}
</ScrollView>;
```

This works, But I wanted to do this using `FlatList`, so tried below given code:

```
 <FlatList
  horizontal={true}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.horizontalView}
  data={weekArray}
  renderItem={_renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.day}
/>;

const _renderItem = (item, index) => {
    <TouchableOpacity
      index={index}
      onPress={() => setIndexSelect(index)}
      key={index}
    >
      <Text>
        {index === weekArray.length - 1 ? ` ${item.day} ` : ` ${item.day} | `}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  }
```

I am getting just blank screen with this code.
I am very new to using `FlatList` , so I am not able to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To use Flatlist, simply you have to pass data which you want to map, and there's a renderItem prop which is used for rendering the data, there's another prop called keyExtractor which is for giving every element a unique

```
<Flatlist 
   data={weekArray}
   renderItem={_renderItem}
   keyExtractor={(item) => item.day}
/>

const _renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
   return (
     //your jsx/code goes here
)}
```

for renderItem you have to add {}.

Comment: I am getting `undefined` text in place of days name

Comment: can you please put your array here?

Answer (score 0):

All you're missing is return statement in **_renderItem** and passing or accessing the value wrong. Use this (Just changed **item** to **{ item }**). You can also use just item but you'll have to access your value as *item.item.days* in such case. Play around with this and you should see expected result.

```
<FlatList
  horizontal={true}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.horizontalView}
  data={weekArray}
  renderItem={_renderItem}
  //keyExtractor={(item) => item.day}
  keyExtractor={({ item, index }) => _renderItem(item, index)}
/>;

const _renderItem = (item, index) => {
    return (<TouchableOpacity
      index={index}
      onPress={() => setIndexSelect(index)}
      key={index}
    >
      <Text>
        {index === weekArray.length - 1 ? ` ${item.day} ` : ` ${item.day} | `}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>)
  }
```